# How to write 'if' without using 'then' or 'end' in Ruby

Tags: ruby, syntax, conditional-statements

I've found three ways to write the same condition in Ruby:

```
#1
if 1==1 
  puts "true" 
end

#2
puts "true" if 1==1

#3
if 1==1  then puts "true" end
```

Why can't I do this?

```
#4
if 1==1 puts "true"
```

I don't understand:

1. Why **then** and **end** are needed in #3, and,
2. Why I need to change the order to get #2 to work.

Statement #4 seems like the most natural way to write this. I don't understand why it's not possible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The "`if x then y end`" syntax is meant for multiline conditionals while the "`y if x`" form is meant for concise single-line conditional statements. The `then` is necessary in the first case to tell Ruby that the condition is over (since Ruby doesn't require parens like C), and the `end` is necessary to tell Ruby that the whole `if` block is over (since it can be multiple lines).

You can replace the `then` with a semicolon, because an end-of-line also signals the end of the condition. You can't get rid of the `end` with a multiline `if`. Either use the second form or the ternary operator if you want a concise one-liner.

For example, suppose

```
x = true
```

the following will evaluate true, and return y

```
x ? y :
=> y
```

likewise, this will evaluate false and return nothing

```
!x ? y :
=>
```

add a term after the ':' for the else case

```
!x ? y : z
=> z
```

Comment: "since Ruby doesn't require parens like C" - I forgot that. Ok, makes sense why 'then' is needed. Didn't know about the semicolon - looks a little strange but it works. Very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The thing is that both ways actually are a natural way to think:

if this is true then do something

do something if this is true

See? Ruby tries to get close to English syntax this way. The *end* is just necessary to end the block, while in the second version, the block is already closed with the *if*.

To actually answer your question, I think there is no chance to get the *then* and *end* removed. Remember Pascal / Delphi? You have a *then* there as well. It's typical only for C-style languages to not have it.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a colon instead of then like this? http://www.java2s.com/Code/Ruby/Statement/layoutanifstatementisbyreplacingthethenwithacolon.htm

There are various ways you could short circuit if you wanted to do so.

The conditional statement is just part of the Ruby syntax to make it more English like.

Comment: For what it's worth, this use of the colon is gone as of Ruby 1.9 - same for the when tests in case statements. See David Black's "Son of 10 things to be aware of in Ruby 1.9"